# trying to convert url to image(getting black image) - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

i tried to convert url  - my code are running a while and worked perfect ( i suspect it might be privilege issue ).

when i'm running the site using vs (the image are not black) - but when i'm hosting the site on iis(local/remote) i'm getting black image.

i didn't found any solution here or in the web,

```
    public WebsiteToImage(string url, string fileName, int? with, int? height)
    {
        // With file  
        m_Url = url;
        m_FileName = fileName;
        m_With = with;
        m_Height = height;

    }

    public Bitmap Generate()
    {
        // Thread  
        var m_thread = new Thread(_Generate);
        m_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        m_thread.Start();
        m_thread.Join();
        return m_Bitmap;
    }

    private void _Generate()
    {
        var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
        browser.Navigate(m_Url);
        browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        browser.Dispose();
    }

    private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Capture  
        var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        browser.ClientSize = new Size(m_With == null ? browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width : (int)m_With, m_Height == null ? browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom : (int)m_Height);
        browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(m_With == null ? browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width : (int)m_With, m_Height == null ? browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom : (int)m_Height);
        browser.BringToFront();
        browser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, browser.Bounds);

        // Save as file?  
        if (m_FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            // Save  
            m_Bitmap.SaveJPG100(m_FileName);
        }
    }
}
public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, string filename)
    {


        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);


        bmp.Save(filename, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did write:

```
m_thread.Start();
m_thread.Join();
```

This way you lose all "benefits" of background process, 'cause you'll need to wait to finish the thread to provide the result...

There's a lot of complications trying to use background worked the way that you used...
Make the things simple and straight.
You'll notice that there's no need to "optimize" with background worker...

Comment: i know that but the main quotation is  why i'm getting black image

Comment: When you run it at VS, is the browser visible when executing "browser.BringToFront();"
I'm sure that it'll not happen when using IIS.
This is a strange way to get a snapshot of browser content...